# How to get out of input in Linux console

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, virtualbox

I have written a program that asks for user input in a loop and only terminates when exit was entered. However, there seems to be a bug in my program so that I can never exit. Is there a Linux shortcut that lets me exit the program even when I am in the user input? I am running Linux in Oracle Virtualbox on a Windows 10 Laptop.

I think the reason might be fgets. Now, using fflush() "test" is printed, but after this the command line expects input again. The function "parse" is specified in the function parser.c but this should not be of relevance for this question.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "parser.c"

int main()
{
    //Ausgabe des "$"
    write(1, "$", 1);
    //Auf Eingabe des Nutzers warten:
    char *input=malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
    fgets(input, 1023, stdin);
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("%s", "test", 5);
    parse(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Post the code into the question and explain the requirement

Comment: If you didn't set signal handlers for SIGINT and SIGQUIT, Ctrl+c and Ctrl+\ could help you terminate your program.

Comment: Thank you! @Kai however, these two shortcuts do not help me. I forgot to mention that I am running this on Oracle Virtualbox and Ctrl+c changes my view. I added this information to the question now.

Comment: @SQLLearner ctrl+c works for me in virtualbox. Maybe you could change the shortcut for virtualbox and have a try.